# Can I get the content of a Site Page and use it inside my SPFx Web part?

Tags: web-part, jquery, spfx, sitepages

I have a webpart which I want to fill with the HTML of a SitePage.aspx. 
If the user fills the SitePage with a Title, 3 blocks of text and an image, I wish to be able to use that exact same content and plug it into my webpart.

What I'm looking for is something like

> var content = document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML

And place this content in my web part. The only difference is, of course, the SitePage.aspx file and my web part are not on the same page and so I can not hope to search for any HTML inside this document.

Is there any workaround for this? It doesn't have to be a string of the HTML-content. If I can just plug the entire page in there, that's fine as well.

Lastly, if it's at all possible to make this work with the SitePage.aspx on a different (sub)site than the web part (sub)site, that would be ideal. If not, I'll figure out a workaround.

Thanks in advance.